# crawling errors on non existing pages

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, qtranslate

Last year I bought a domain name and started blogging here :

http://www.lengrand.fr/

As a french guy, I wanted my website to be bilingual and used qtranslate for some time.
But I quickly realized that it was better writing more articles than spend loads of time translating the same articles. . .
My blog is english only for the last 6 months now. What I did was simply disable qtranslate and remove any special stuff.

My problem is that google keep trying to crawl my french pages, and I always have a lot of 404 on pages that do not exist any more. Here are some examples.

fr/tag/adblocker/ 404 14/04/12
fr/category/tips/ 404 02/04/12
fr/ 404 22/02/12
fr/tag/language/ 404 03/04/12

Question is, how can I be sure to remove all those pages from the index ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create or edit your .htaccess file and add the following.

```
redirect 301 /fr/ http://www.lengrand.fr/
```

This should update the search engine's results so they now know the folder /fr/ doesn't exist anymore and they try to find the article without /fr/

So if someone would go to http://www.lengrand.fr/fr/category/tips/ it will directly go to http://www.lengrand.fr/category/tips/ without delay and tell the search engine the page has move to that new url.

Comment: I updated the .htaccess and the redirection is efective, thanks. Let's wait and see if gg stops crawling for /fr pages.

Comment: It is possible some other websites still redirects to your /fr/ pages. You can not change that however, so getting some 404 errors is not a problem, as long as your catch those pages and help the visitors to the correct page.